# PHP struggles. Error 404

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling, edit, crud

Trying to make a crud function/contact list. The user is brought to this page after they log in:

[image]
With a click of the edit function, I hope to take the user to a page that allows them to edit the contact details. Currently struggling to have the link function properly.

The link photo is my /view file. Which looks like this:

```
<?php 

session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['u_uid'])){

$uid = $_SESSION['u_id'];

require_once('connect.php');
$ReadSql = "SELECT * FROM `contact` WHERE users_id=$uid ORDER BY Name";
$res = mysqli_query($connection, $ReadSql);

?>

<head>
<title>Motoko</title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

 <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>
</head>
<body> 
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <table class="table">
        <tr>

            <th><strong>Name</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Company</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Title</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Phone</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Email</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Address</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Extras</strong></th>
        </tr>
        <?php 
        while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
        ?>
        <tr> 
            <td><?php echo $r['Name']; ?></td> 
            <td><?php echo $r['Company']; ?></td> 
            <td><?php echo $r['Title']; ?></td> 
            <td><?php echo $r['Phone']; ?></td> 
            <td><?php echo $r['Email']; ?></td> 
            <td><?php echo $r['Address']; ?></td> 
            <td><a href="crud/update.php?id=<?php echo $r['id'] ?>">Edit</a></td>
            <td><input type="button" onClick="deleteme(<?php echo $r['u_uid']; ?>)" name="Delete" value="Delete"></td>
             </tr>
 <!-- Javascript function for deleting data -->
 <script language="Javascript">
 function deleteme(delid)
 {
 if(confirm("Are you sure you want to Delete?")){
 window.location.href='crud/delete.php';
 }
 } 
 </script>
        <?php } ?>
    </table>
</div>
</body>

</html>

<?php

}else{

header("Location: http://motoko.sorainsurance.com.au"); 

}

?>
```

This would then take them to the /update file. Which starts like:

```
 <?php
 error_reporting();
 require_once('connect.php');
   $id = $_GET['id'];
   $SelSql = "SELECT * FROM `contact` WHERE id=$id";
   $res = mysqli_query($connection, $SelSql);
   $r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);

  if(isset($_POST) & !empty($_POST)){
    $name =  mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['name']);
    $comp =  mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['comp']);
    $title =  mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['title']);
    $phone =  mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['urstel']);
    $email =  mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['email']);
    $location =  mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['location']);


  $UpdateSql = "UPDATE `contact` SET Name='$name', Company='$comp', 
Title='$title', Phone='$phone', Email='$email', Address='$location' WHERE id=$id"; 

    $res = mysqli_query($connection, $UpdateSql);
   if($res){
     echo $smsg = "Successfully updated data.";
     echo  header('location: view.php');
   }else{
     echo $fmsg = "Failed to update data.";
    }
}
```

Any idea why the error keeps popping up? So confused and struggling to progress :(

Many thanks!

Comment: Sorry can you post the link in the browser whenever 404 error is shown?

Comment: `404` means that the page doesn't exist. I'm guessing you don't have a file called `delete.php` in a folder called `crud`. In addition to this, your script is vulnerable to [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), your brackets don't line up on your `if` conditional, and you also can't have **any** output to the DOM before calling `header()` (which in itself should not have an `echo`).

Comment: error link --> http://motoko.sorainsurance.com.au/crud/crud/update.php?id=75

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`404` error code indicate that, you are not request correct `URL`.

> This would then take them to the /update file

You mentioned, the request will go to `update` file, But your request `URL` is `crud/update.php`.

Now, request `URL` depends on relativity of the file. So, whether you view file exists at root folder and `update.php` under `crud` folder ?

**==Edited==**

(referring your latest comment)It seems like, your `update.php` and `view.php` exists in same folder, then you should simply change the request

```
crud/update.php
```

to

```
update.php
```

You don't need to mention the folder path in your request.

Comment: All my files, that is, the delete, view, update are located in the crud folder.

Comment: @kerrysun I have updated my post. You can update your code as well.

Comment: if I could just stab your brain for one more second. I can now update the contacts. But it comes up with --> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/sorainsurance1/public_html/motoko/crud/update.php:1) in /home/sorainsurance1/public_html/motoko/crud/update.php on line 23

Comment: @kerrysun You manipulating the header, there are lots of existing post on this. You can try one by one. All the best :-)